# Getting a Java ProcessBuilder error when trying to run a Powershell script

Tags: java, powershell

I am trying to run a Powershell script (PS1) file from my java program.

Here's my Java code :

```
 for     (  ;  ; )  {
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -Command \"C:\\Java_Scratch2\\University.PS1"); 
     Process p = pb.start();
     p.waitFor();   
    }
```

but when I try to execute, I get the following error in Windows CMD :

```
C:\Java_Scratch2>java ParentClassBatchRunner
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v
1.0\powershell.exe -Command "C:\Java_Scratch2\University.PS1": CreateProcess err
or=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at ParentClassBatchRunner.main(ParentClassBatchRunner.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find th
e file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

I've tried  to change formatting of it, swapping  `~` for spaces, etc.  But still stuck . thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misquoted one argument.

But anyway, you should not use this form of ProcessBuilder. Invoke it like this:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "-Command",
    "C:\\Java_Scratch2\\University.PS1"
);

final Process p = pb.start();

// and don't forget to check the result of p.waitFor()
```

Comment: Thanks so very much !

Comment: Isn't "-File" option more suitable in such case?