# Execute a C# program via PowerShell remotely using Java

Tags: java, c#, powershell, rpc

Environment: Windows 10 (Java) -> Windows 10 (PowerShell and C#)
Java:        1.8.0_252

Trying to remotely execute a C# program via PowerShell from Java.  Seem to be having issues with the path. The C# program is in a subdirectory under a shared drive.

```
import java.io.*;
public class CallCSharp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "/c",
             "\\SharedDrive\\Data\\Bin\\Program.exe \\\\10.1.1.1 -u user -p password");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = builder.start();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while (true) {
               line = r.readLine();
               if (line == null) {
                    break;
               }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error returned is

```
The term '\SharedDrive\Data\Bin\Program.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

The path is correct and the C# program can be run successfully.
Suspect I am not formatting the `ProcessBuilder` call correctly.

Comment: Can you try with absolute path to the exe.

Comment: @YannCha - please provide an example.

Comment: similar command in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543828/getting-a-java-processbuilder-error-when-trying-to-run-a-powershell-script?rq=1

Comment: @YannCha - tried a C: at the beginning of the path string -- no change.

Comment: @YannCha - also, since I am dealing with a shared drive and a RPC, I doubt the drive letter has any relevance.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So, it shouldn't be `\\\\ShareDrive` then?

Comment: @notjustme - I tried that - \\\\SharedDrive - and I get "The network path was not found".  I can ping the server.  Maybe still a network issue?

Comment: I'd guess, I'm no Java coder but it just didn't make sense the way you escaped `\` in every other occurence other than with the network share.

Comment: @notjustme - good point.  I'm going to look into that first to be sure.